# Parece que a tag [font] é uma fonte de problemas, o que podemos fazer para resolver?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Veja as perguntas em [font](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font). No começo o uso foi bem intencionado. Mas depois vemos o uso generalizado para qualquer coisa que envolva fontes de letras e símbolos.

Devemos ter uma *tag* `css-font` separada para tratar de assuntos que envolvam fonte? Note que já temos [css-font-face](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-font-face) e [css-font-size](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-font-size). Alguns acharão que elas são muito específicas. Eu não acho, concorda? Outros acharão que elas são as mais adequadas e que uma `css-font` é desnecessária.

Então [font](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/font) ficaria para o uso de fonte fora do contexto de CSS? Ou está bom do jeito que é hoje tudo misturado? Pode piorar no futuro?

Qual a melhor forma de tratar isso para manter mais organizado?

Comment: bigown tens sempre um títulos bem sugestivos :)

Comment: A ideia não foi minha, segui o fluxo do povo :) pena que eu seja bem ruim em trocadilhos. Uma hora eu acero um em cheio :)